# html не видит атрибут onclick

Tags: javascript, html5

С помощью js хочу добавить атрибут onclick, но не получается

```js
function printA() {
  console.log('a')
}

function test() {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.id = 'test';
  btn.onclick = 'printA()';
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<input id="fI" value="5">
<input id="sI" value="8">
<button onclick="test();">go</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

[image: взял с Elements]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
btn.onclick = printA;
```

---

```
btn.setAttribute("onclick", 'printA()');
```

Comment: Не помогает. Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: @ТоксичныйСандаль Помогает. Вариантов нет. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Не стал проверять консоль. Теперь все понял

Answer (score 3):

В HTML `onclick="printA();"` это то же самое, что в скрипте

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  printA();
};
```

Cвойство onclick ожидает функцию,
а вы `btn.onclick = "printA()"` присваиваете ей **строку** `"printA()"`

1. Или `btn.onclick = printA` — т.е. присвоить функцию, через её имя.
2. Или `btn.setAttribute("onclick", "printA();")`

А вообще, лучше не использовать ни то, ни другое)

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", '<button class="moo">test</button>');
});

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches(".moo")) return;
  // Если кликнули НЕ на элемент с классом "moo" - прервать функцию;

  // Иначе, вызвать printA   
  printA();
});

function printA() {
  console.log('a')
}
```

```html
<button id="go">go</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Не все свойства, присваиваемые элементам в JS коде, становятся HTML-атрибутами.
2. Значением атрибута `onclick` в HTML по необходимости должна быть строка. Но значением свойства `onclick` в коде JS [должна быть ссылка на функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).

Вот так кнопка работает, хоть атрибута в коде кнопки вы не увидите:

```js
function printA() {
  console.log('a')
}

function test() {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.id = 'test';
  btn.textContent = 'test';
  btn.onclick = printA;
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<input id="fI" value="5">
<input id="sI" value="8">
<button onclick="test();">go</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```